# How can I use ABCpdf to retrieve custom document properties?

Tags: c#, abcpdf

[This page](http://www.websupergoo.com/helppdf9net/source/4-examples/14-setprops.htm) gives a helpful example of how to set custom document properties for a pdf.

So I've done this (and I've verified that the custom property is set in the file):

```
Doc theDoc = new Doc();
int theID = theDoc.AddObject("<< >>");
theDoc.SetInfo(-1, "/Info:Ref", theID.ToString());
theDoc.SetInfo(theID, "/Company:Text", "ACME");
theDoc.Save(FileName);
```

I'm trying to retrieve the property at a later time. I've tried:

```
Doc theDoc = new Doc();
theDoc.Read(FileName);
int theID = theDoc.AddObject("<< >>");
theDoc.SetInfo(-1, "/Info:Ref", theID.ToString());
return theDoc.GetInfo(theID, "/Company:Text"); //returns empty string
```

and

```
//...read theDoc
int theID = theDoc.GetInfoInt(-1, "/Info");
return theDoc.GetInfo(theID, "/Company:Text"); //returns empty string
```

Anybody have a clue as to how I can retrieve that property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found another way to set these values:

```
if (theDoc.GetInfo(-1, "/Info") == "")
    theDoc.SetInfo(-1, "/Info:Ref", theDoc.AddObject("<< >>").ToString());
theDoc.SetInfo(-1, "/Info*/Company:Text", "ACME");
```

After setting the values in this way, I'm able to retrieve them like so:

```
if (theDoc.GetInfo(-1, "/Info") == "")
    theDoc.SetInfo(-1, "/Info:Ref", theDoc.AddObject("<< >>").ToString());
string companyName = theDoc.GetInfo(-1, "/Info*/Company:Text");
```